# How can i get Azure database metrics using the az cmdlets in Powershell?

Tags: azure, powershell, jenkins

I am trying to get an Azure database metrics

```
  $servers = Get-AzSqlServer
```

then i use

```
 $db_metric_storage = $db_resource | Get-AzMetric -MetricName 'storage'
```

but this gives an error

```
 Get-AzSqlServer : The term 'Get-AzSqlServer' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet
```

How can i get the metrics , specifically percentage used for a database using powershell ?

Comment: Did you google the error? This usually means you have to install the underlying library  which is az.sql in this case https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.sql/?view=azps-10.0.0

Comment: Yes i did ... i did install the module

Comment: can i get metrics and server with az command instead of calling Get-SqlServer and Get-Metrics ?

Comment: I checked here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/sql?view=azure-cli-latest and it doesn't look like it but I suggest you try it and see. I suggest you confirm that the module is installed as expected. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/powershellget/get-installedmodule?view=powershellget-2.x How are you running this code? In the cloud shell or locally?

Comment: Ok , but i am running through Jenkins. Is there a way i can see or define the version oif Powershell to use in Jenkins ?

Comment: I have checked , its installed

Comment: When I run `Get-InstalledModule Az.Sql` I get version 3.11.0 and I can run `Get-AzSqlServer` OK. What version do you have?

Comment: Have you ensured it's installed on the Jenkins server? I haven't used Jenkins but I assume it can just run cmdlines fine. I assume you ran `Get-InstalledModule Az.Sql` in a Jenkins step?

Comment: if i run this from powershell ise i get version 4.7.0. If i run it from Jenkins , it says no such match was found . So do i need to install it before i run the script ?  If so do i just do Install-Module Az.Sql ?

Comment: still doesnt work , says  "Install-NuGetClientBinaries : Exception calling "ShouldContinue" with "2" argument(s): "Windows PowerShell is in 
NonInteractive mode. Read and Prompt functionality is not available."

Comment: Issue is it runs on the machine in powershell ise , but if i put it in a jenkins job under a powershell task it gives the errors above

Comment: So we have established it's actually _not_ installed. Why don't you edit your original question to include the information that you are running this in a Jenkins job and I'll google how to install a powershell library on to Jenkins

Comment: The easiest thing to do is get your "Jenkins Administrator" to install Az modules globally on the Jenkins server. Is that an option?

Comment: Have tried cant seem to get it to work .. only the az cms work not the function calls like Get-Server etc

Comment: Did you Jenkins admin get on the server and globally install the module?

Comment: yes we did and still no diff

Comment: So now when you run `Get-InstalledModule Az.Sql` insdie a Jenkins job it gives you a version number? If you have a Jenkins admin, this is something they need to work out